# Is there a way to let the gdb repeat the same instrcutions on every start again?

Tags: gdb

I am currently debugging a program with gdb.
I have to start gdb over and over again and do the same steps:

set a breakpoint,
run,
print a variable,
quit

Is there a way to let gdb do that automatically for me? Probably a script that could be attached as a parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it either by `-x file` option or by `-ex command` option. From [Gdb manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/File-Options.html#File-Options):

```
-command file
-x file
Execute commands from file file. The contents of this file is evaluated exactly as the source command would. See Command files. 
-eval-command command
-ex command
Execute a single gdb command.
This option may be used multiple times to call multiple commands. It may also be interleaved with `-command' as required.

          gdb -ex 'target sim' -ex 'load' \
             -x setbreakpoints -ex 'run' a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

The interwebs differ on whether the name of the file is .gdbrc or .gdbinit, but GDB will read this file from your home directory on start-up, and it can give any GDB command (including setting breakpoints).

Also check out [http://www.andrews.edu/~seidel/gdb.help](http://www.andrews.edu/%7Eseidel/gdb.help)

Comment: Just checked the man page to see what the file is called, it's the .gdbinit You can tell gdb to ignore this with -n or -nx Anyway, there is a better way for my purpose I just found in the man page (sorry!): -x FILE, -command=FILE Execute GDB commands from file file. One can write the commands taken by the interpreter in that file, one each line.

Comment: This answer is wrong: GDB will not read `.gdbrc` nor `.gdbin`.  It _will_ read `.gdbinit`