# GDB is not taking the instruction placed in the ~/.gdbint and/or ~/.gdbrc file

Tags: gdb, gdbinit

I am using GDB to debug my C program.
And since I am handling `SIGUSR1` in my program.
So once I run the gdb with my program executable like -

```
gdb <my_executable>
```

under the gdb prompt `(gdb)` I need to enter -

```
handle SIGUSR1 nostop noprint pass
```

since I need to do this every time, I wanted to place this `handle` command in the init script.
So after googling, I got to know about the `~/.gdbrc` and `~/.gdbinit`. I tried to place the `handle` command in both the files, but still I don't see that handle command is executed once after gdb reads the symbols from the executable.

What could be wrong with this?

**Edit**: *GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2.2*

**Edit 2**: My .gdbrc file content looks like -

```
 echo "hello from gdbrc"
 handle SIGUSR1 nostop noprint pass
 run 204
```

**Edit 3**: Even I tried with GNU *gdb (GDB) 8.1.3* Still I'm facing the same issue.

**Edit 4**: The `~/.gdbrc` and `~/.gdbinit` are given full access permission -

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 darshan grp      68 Oct  9 22:14 .gdbint
-rwxrwxrwx   1 darshan grp      67 Oct  9 22:14 .gdbrc
```

**Edit 5**: I had named the file wrongly as "`.gdbint`" instead of "`.gdbinit`".
After renaming, I found with the `GDB 8.1.3`, it is being read at the startup. However, with `GDB 7.2.2` still I see the problem - `.gdbinit` file is not read at the startup.

And `~/.gdbrc` is NOT a right filename to use and won't be recognized by GDB.

Comment: Could you add the output of `gdb --version | head -1` to your question?

Comment: If you add `echo done loading\n` to the end of your `~/.gdbinit` file, and run gdb again, do you see the `done loading` line?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I tried adding echo command inside both the files, but I don't see the print in the output. However, when I pass .gdbrc as an -X argument then I could see the output. So seems like the.gdbint / .gdbrc files are not executed at the beginning

Comment: Even I tried with 
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1.3
Still I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Your listings show `-rwxrwxrwx   1 darshan grp      68 Oct  9 22:14 .gdbint` rather than `.gdbinit`; was that just a cut and paste error?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You are right. My bad. I had created the file with .gdbint. After changing it to .gdbinit, with GDB version 8.1.3, it is working but not with GDB version 7.2.2. Can I assume GDB 7.2.2 didnt support .gdbinit?

Another question is - what is the different purposes between ~/.gdbinit and ~/.gdbrc ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I assume GDB 7.2.2 didnt support .gdbinit?

GDB has supported reading `~/.gdbinit` since *forever* (at least since version 4.0, but probably much earlier).

You should be able to figure out what's happening by looking at the output from

```
strace -e file gdb --version |& grep gdbinit
```

Here is what I see:

```
stat("/home/employedrussian/.gdbinit", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=629, ...}) = 0
stat(".gdbinit", 0x7ffe51ef72f0)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**Update:**

> When I run the command, I see no output with GDB 7.2.2 But with GDB 8.1.3, I see the same output like you.

Ok, it seems that you have a broken version of GDB 7.2.2. Try newer version.

I could not find any bug about GDB not reading `.gdbinit`, but maybe it was broken at some point temporarily.

---

> what is the different purposes between ~/.gdbinit and ~/.gdbrc

The former is read by GDB, the latter isn't (where did you get the idea that GDB would read it?).

**Update:**

> I thought just like many other linux application

It *is* a UNIX shell convention to read `~/.${SHELL}rc` file on startup, and may other applications do so as well. But GDB isn't one of them.

> http://stackoverflow.com/a/7195718/5347487

That answer is wrong.

Comment: > `strace -e file gdb --version |& grep gdbinit`

When I run the command, I see no output with `GDB 7.2.2`

But with `GDB 8.1.3`, I see the same output like you.

> `The former is read by GDB, the latter isn't (where did you get the idea that GDB would read it?).`

I thought just like many other linux application an *rc file would be present for GDB also and googled it and found this answer -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7195718/5347487

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to look if there was any bug in gdb.
I wish I could&amp;amp;amp;#39;ve moved to newer version of GDB. But got a problem - when I try to place a breakpoint using a function name - it says, function name is not found, and asks if it is part of a shared library. But if I pretend the function name with `__be_` then it accepts the breakpoint. Not able to understand this behaviour and reason for this incompatibility. Binary is generated using ICC compiler for a x86_64 architecture.

Comment: I learnt today that while building GDB source code, we can pass some flags to define it's behaviour. So I was wondering could it be possible that the GDB 7.2.2 that I'm using is built with an option not to read .gdbinit file?

Comment: @DarshanL It's also possible to edit the source of GDB and introduce bugs. If you are using modified version of GDB, then we can't _know_ what these modifications were. You'll have to figure that out yourself.